# Not able to read and write holding registers directly from modbus server (pymodbus)

Tags: python, networking, tcp, pymodbus, pymodbustcp

I currently have a local modbus-TCP network on my computer, consisting of a modbus server and two modbus clients. I want it to be a network of one server and one client, but currently have not been able to write and read holding registers from my server hence the need for a redundant extra client.

My code is as follows, I have simplified it considerably for illustrative purposes

SERVER.PY

```
from pymodbus.server import StartTcpServer
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSparseDataBlock, ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext
from pymodbus.version import version
from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification

store = ModbusSlaveContext(hr=ModbusSparseDataBlock({0x00: [0]*0xff}))
context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)
identity = ModbusDeviceIdentification()
identity.VendorName = 'Pymodbus'
identity.ProductCode = 'PM'
identity.VendorUrl = 'http://github.com/bashwork/pymodbus/'
identity.ProductName = 'Pymodbus Server'
identity.ModelName = 'Pymodbus Server'
identity.MajorMinorRevision = version.short()

StartTcpServer(context=context, identity=identity, address=("0.0.0.0", 502))
```

CLIENT1.PY

```
from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient

while True:
    client.write_registers(0, [power, current, energy]) # variables defined earlier
    feedback = client.read_registers(4, 3, unit=1)
    # operations now commence on feedback variable
```

CLIENT2.PY

```
import numpy as np
from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient

while True:
    client.write_registers(4, [analytics, analytics2, analytics3]) # variables defined earlier
    system = client.read_registers(0, 3, unit=1)
    # operations now commence on system variable
```

I want the CLIENT2.PY to become the new server, i.e. something like the following

NEW_SERVER.PY

```
from pymodbus.server import StartTcpServer
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSparseDataBlock, ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext
from pymodbus.version import version
from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification

store = ModbusSlaveContext(hr=ModbusSparseDataBlock({0x00: [0]*0xff}))
context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)
identity = ModbusDeviceIdentification()
identity.VendorName = 'Pymodbus'
identity.ProductCode = 'PM'
identity.VendorUrl = 'http://github.com/bashwork/pymodbus/'
identity.ProductName = 'Pymodbus Server'
identity.ModelName = 'Pymodbus Server'
identity.MajorMinorRevision = version.short()

server = StartTcpServer(context=context, identity=identity, address=("0.0.0.0", 502))

while True:
    server.write_registers(4, [analytics, analytics2, analytics3]) # variables defined earlier
    system = server.read_registers(0, 3, unit=1)
    # operations now commence on system variable
```

CLIENT1.PY should remain the same as before in this example.

The issue is that I have not yet found a way to write to holding registers directly from the server, and instead have to create a client to do so, whilst the real server just sits there doing nothing but running. Help would be much appreciated